# Python function returning None despite having return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below function is returning None despite having return statement. This seems to be a simple problem but i am unable to figure out the solution being a python beginner. The findurls function works perfectly but the second function -"murls" seems to have a problem.

```
def findurls(url):
    s = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    txt = BeautifulSoup(s.text, 'lxml')
    page = []
    for link in txt.findAll('a'):
        page.append(link.get('href'))
    return s, page
def murls(page):
    match = ['contact','contact us','contact-us','Contact Us','Contact us', 'Contact', 'Contact US','contactus','ContactUS','ContactUs']
    matching = [n for n in match if any(n in i for i in page)]
    return matching

details = murls(findurls("https://www.genre.com/"))
print(details)
```

The output generated by function findurls is as follows :-

```
['https://globalpage-prod.webex.com/join', 'http://www.genre.com/clientlogin/?c=n', 'http://www.genre.com/?c=n', '#nav', '#', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/na/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/international/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/property-engineering-marine/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/auto-motor/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/surety-bond/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/casualty/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/na/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/international/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/property-engineering-marine/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/auto-motor/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/surety-bond/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/casualty/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/all/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/publications/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/multimedia/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/all/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/publications/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/multimedia/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/contactus/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/careers/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/careers/job-posting/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/careers/recent-graduates/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/careers/internships/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/careers/job-posting/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/careers/recent-graduates/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/careers/internships/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/meet-genre/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/senior-management-team/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/financial-info/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/press-releases/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/privacy-at-genre/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/meet-genre/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/senior-management-team/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/financial-info/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/press-releases/?c=n', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/privacy-at-genre/?c=n', '/knowledge/blog/wildfire-season-is-here-underwriting-factors-and-tools-for-the-wildfire-peril-en.html', '/knowledge/blog/wildfire-season-is-here-underwriting-factors-and-tools-for-the-wildfire-peril-en.html', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/wildfire-season-is-here-underwriting-factors-and-tools-for-the-wildfire-peril-en.html', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/contributors/marc-dahling.html?contributorTabSearch=blogPosts', '/knowledge/blog/what-does-the-us-supreme-courts-recent-lgbtq-ruling-mean-for-businesses-and-epli-en.html', '/knowledge/blog/what-does-the-us-supreme-courts-recent-lgbtq-ruling-mean-for-businesses-and-epli-en.html', '/knowledge/blog/individual-disability-in-the-us-behind-the-numbers-en.html', '/knowledge/blog/individual-disability-in-the-us-behind-the-numbers-en.html', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/individual-disability-in-the-us-behind-the-numbers-en.html', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/contributors/steve-woods.html?contributorTabSearch=blogPosts', '/knowledge/publications/cmchina20-1-en.html', '/knowledge/publications/cmchina20-1-en.html', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/publications/cmchina20-1-en.html', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/contributors/frank-wang.html?contributorTabSearch=blogPosts', '/knowledge/blog/contributors/', '/contactus/', 'https://cta-redirect.hubspot.com/cta/redirect/525060/3d7afa2a-d966-40c4-860a-07709aacf6cd', '#tab1', '#tab2', '#tab3', '#tab1', '/knowledge', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/publications/uwfocus20-1-luckmann-en.html', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/publications/uwfocus20-1-luckmann-en.html', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/contributors/annika-luckmann.html', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/publications/uwfocus20-1-luckmann-en.html', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/contributors/tim-fletcher.html', "javascript:trackRecommentedBlog('https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/riots-and-civil-commotion-disquieting-times-ahead-en.html')", "javascript:trackRecommentedBlog('https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/riots-and-civil-commotion-disquieting-times-ahead-en.html')", 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/contributors/tim-eppert.html', "javascript:trackRecommentedBlog('https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/changes-in-cancer-classification-how-do-they-impact-critical-illness-insurance-en.html')", "javascript:trackRecommentedBlog('https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/changes-in-cancer-classification-how-do-they-impact-critical-illness-insurance-en.html')", 'https://twitter.com/Gen_Re', '#tab2', '/reinsurance-solutions/#tab=-1', '/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/na/', '/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/na/', '/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/na/', '/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/international/', '/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/international/', '/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/international/', '/reinsurance-solutions/#tab=0', '/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/auto-motor/', '/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/auto-motor/', '/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/auto-motor/', '/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/casualty/', '/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/casualty/', '/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/casualty/', '/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/property-engineering-marine/', '/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/property-engineering-marine/', '/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/property-engineering-marine/', '/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/surety-bond/', '/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/surety-bond/', '/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/surety-bond/', '#tab3', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/contributors/sandra-mitic.html', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/contributors/sandra-mitic.html', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/contributors/roman-hannig.html', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/contributors/roman-hannig.html', '/careers/', '/terms/', '/sitemap/', '/imprint/', '/aboutus/privacy-at-genre/', 'http://www.genre.com/?c=n', 'http://www.linkedin.com/company/gen-re', 'https://twitter.com/Gen_Re', 'https://www.youtube.com/user/GenRePerspective/playlists', 'http://www.slideshare.net/genreperspective', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/na/', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/lifehealth/international/', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/property-engineering-marine/', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/auto-motor/', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/surety-bond/', 'https://www.genre.com/reinsurance-solutions/property-casualty/casualty/', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/all/', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/publications/', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/blog/', 'https://www.genre.com/knowledge/multimedia/', 'http://knowledge.genre.com/subscribe?utm_campaign=Subscription%20Management%20Center&utm_medium=footer&utm_source=website', 'https://www.genre.com/contactus/', 'mailto:Genre_Feedback_EN@genre.com?subject=Reg: Gen Re Website Feedback', 'https://www.genre.com/careers/', 'https://www.genre.com/careers/job-posting/', 'https://www.genre.com/careers/recent-graduates/', 'https://www.genre.com/careers/internships/', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/meet-genre/', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/senior-management-team/', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/financial-info/', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/press-releases/', 'https://www.genre.com/aboutus/privacy-at-genre/'])
```

Whereas when i use both functions together, it produces the below output - an empty list :-

```
[]
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Your `findurls` function returns a tuple. Your `murls` function returns a list. Neither of them returns None.

Comment: Part of what `findurls` apparently returns is `r`, which is not defined in your code. You should probably post a [mre].

Comment: I have edited the code for the outputs generated by both functions.

Comment: apology for the inconvenience

Comment: i have corrected the typo, please look into the code now

Comment: To provide  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you need to define all parameters such as headers in findurls.

Comment: Following your latest edit you are passing the result of `findurls`, which is `(s, page)`, to `murls`, which expects `page`. Can you see the problem with that?

Comment: change `return s, page` to `return page` - you are not using `s`

Comment: Yes, i got the point, i am giving two inputs to murls instead of just one -"page". But i want to use "s" in further functions, so i need to keep it, then how can i make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findurls` returns two objects

```
return s, page
```

but `murls` only wants one, `page`.

Option 1: separate the calls into separate lines so you can select what arguments to pass to `murls`.

```
s, page = findurls("https://www.genre.com/")
details = murls(page)
print(details)
```

Option 2: use indexing to pick out the second item from the tuple.

```
details = murls(findurls("https://www.genre.com/")[1])
print(details)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in `murls` function. You are supposed to pass a page but you are passing a URL. So `page` becomes `https://www.genre.com` which will not match according to your code making `matching, None`. This when passed to `findurls` will match nothing as your page is empty. So you get an empty list. You should try to fetch page in `mruls` and then apply logic.

Comment: It still produces an empty list.

Comment: You should just print what you are passing to `findurls` in your code and see it is valid HTML. I do not know what code you have altered.